# Keep Mission Flag but edit Kerbal Flag?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I'm trying to recreate the Apollo 11 mission once more... (0.90 update stuffed up my save) But this time I want to do it a little differently...

You can choose your **save files** flag by going to the Flagpole outside the KSC and doing so..
You can choose your **missions** flag by going to the respective menu inside the VAB/SPH.

Can you choose your **Kerbals** flag or edit it via mods or save file editing? Because I want the NASA flag on the Apollo ship and the American flag in my Kerbals hands.

Please, I really need this. xD

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can try:

1. Go on EVA.
2. Quicksave
3. Open the quicksave file in a text editor (like Notepad++). The file will be named quicksave.sfs, and you can find it in `<path/to/KSP>/saves/<your save name>/`
4. Search for your EVA'd Kerbal's name in the file. It should be right after some lines that say `VESSEL { pid = <abc>, name = <your Kerbal's name>`.
5. Look down some for `PART { name = kerbalEVA ...`
6. Later in that block, there should be a line that says `flag = <path/to/flag>`.
7. Change that line to the path to the desired flag. You will need everything after GameData. Pay attention to capitalization because I am pretty sure that it is case sensitive and leave off the file extension.
8. Save your changes, switch back to KSP, and load the quicksave file.
9. Plant the flag and see if it worked.

**Example**:

Assuming you EVA'd Bill Kerman and want to change the flag to the Satellite flag (which is found in `<path/to/KSP>/GameData/Squad/Flags/Satellite.png`)

The quicksave.sfs:

```
<snip>
VESSEL
{
  pid = <abc>
  name = Bill Kerman
  <snip>
  PART
  {
    name = kerbalEVA
    <snip>
    flag = Squad/Flags/default   // change this to "Squad/Flags/Satellite"
    <etc>
```

You should be able to change any placed flag in a similar way.

Comment: Hmm.. Ill try that. Souunds **very interesting**. Thanks.

Comment: Wait... wait wait wait wait... Could I... Send up a kerbal with **a** flag, and dock him with a ship with another?

Comment: I believe that the Kerbal's flag would get reset when boarding the ship to whatever flag the capsule has assigned.

As far as docking two ships with different flags, I do not know what happens. I have not tried that before. I usually just use my personal flag on all missions. I think the vessel flag will be set to whatever flag the root part has assigned, but the two ships might revert to their original flags when undocking.

Comment: I've docked before. Ships keep their own. I don't know about the Kerbals though. Still trying....

Comment: Either way, it's a good answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: So sorry for never getting back to you Michael. I forgot all about this post! Your answer was correct! It wasn't just easy. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

There are only save file flags and mission flags. Selecting a mission flag sets it for both the vehicle and the kerbals assigned to it, and there's no way to set them separately.

I've searched for a plugin that would help but haven't found any.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a way? Not even through heavy editing? A mod?

Comment: @Finn I'm sure it's possible with either editing the parts directly or using a plugin to do so. It's just that nobody has created such a thing yet.

Comment: Mmm... Ok. I'll have to see what I can do then. Thanks for the answer.